# Disable Comments in document details page

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

In document details page, under the document preview, users can add/ view comments. How could i disable/hide this Comments area?

Thanks in advance.

(Alfresco Community v5.0.0 (d r99759-b2) schema 8022)

Comment: There is not a simple "disable comments" checkbox anywhere. This is going to involve several different customizations/extensions because you probably want to remove not only the field but also all of the "Comment" links in both the document details page and the document library. Start by reading http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/dev-extensions-share-surf-extension-modules.html.

Comment: Thank you Jeff. Will do that.